# have nginix assign a process to one connection

Tags: python, nginx, tornado

this is my current nginx.conf file:

```
user www-data;worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    #connections a worker can handle: ulimit -n
    worker_connections 1024;
    use epoll;
   # multi_accept on;
}

http{

upstream pumpkins{
server localhost:8000;
server localhost:8001;
server localhost:8002;
server localhost:8003;
}

proxy_next_upstream error;

server{
listen 80;
#listen localhost;
#server_name localhost;

# Allow file uploads
client_max_body_size 50M;

location / {
    proxy_pass_header Server;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
    proxy_pass http://pumpkins;
}

}

}
```

I HAVEN'T done any async coding in tornado as yet to handle connections concurrently but I was wondering is there a way to have nginx assign a process to a connection and stay with that connection till the client logs off or disconnects, or is this something that would have to be done in tornado/python? if so how would I go about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [session persistence](https://www.nginx.com/products/session-persistence/)

Comment: wow that's awesome. It would be worth the $1900/year...I think. do you have experience using the session persistence? any other way I could implement it if I didn't want to use nginx? thanks a bunch man.

Comment: In my company we use haproxy also provide the same (similar?) feature.

Answer (score 0):

so seems if you don't want to use nginx plus and pay that fee you can simply implement the ip_hash directive. It causes nginx to uniquely assign each client to a server for the duration of their session. tested locally and on my production site. more info [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html#nginx_load_balancing_with_ip_hash)